# Developing an external Google drive sdk application

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Im  quite new to developing apps that make use of google drive and google api in general. I would like to know whether it is possible to have an application that exposes files saved on google drive without users having to login to their own google drive account. So in a sense the app would have an account and would list the documents that are currently stored on drive and users would be able to click on them ( via Google picker and not Drive UI) and view them.
Note: The app is an external ASP.NET MVC web application.
      I've looked at all the authentication samples available (DrEdit etc) on the Google dev      site but now of them seem to address my problem.

Comment: Do you want all the users of your application to get access to a common Drive or do you want your application to save data to each user's Drive?

Comment: I want all the users of my application to get access to a common Drive. They should be able to read and upload files to that same common Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could manually run through the authentication against your own Drive account, and then store the initial access token and refresh tokens in your CredentialStore implementation, which your app will continue to use.

CredentialStore is from the Java API - I'm sure there are equivalents in the .NET API.

Comment: If you don't to handle the authorization flow in your app, you can retrieve a set of access and refresh token from the [OAuth Playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground): make sure to enter your own client ID and secret, add `https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/` as an authorized redirect URI and you're good to go.